# Al limpiar buffer de entrada la consola espera hasta que se teclee algo

Tags: c, entrada, consola, fgets, stdin

En el proyecto de clase nos han pedido que al introducir una cadena, si esta es nula lo debe indicar y tiene que solicitar nuevamente una cadena, esta parte ya la he resuelto. En caso de que la cadena sea mas larga de lo pedido, el programa lo debe indicar y debe pedir otra cadena. En este caso particular la cadena no puede ser mayor de 15 pero aun asi le reservo 200 bytes:

```
char cadena[200]
```

Ahora, en el caso de que alguien introduzca una cadena de mas de 200 caracteres, tras mostrar "Longitud excesiva" en la consola aparecia el resto de la cadena almacenada en el buffer. Para solucionar esto me dijeron que limpiara el buffer con el siguiente codigo:

```
        char c;
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

El problema es que tras limpiar el buffer la consola se queda esperando hasta que se pulsa 'intro'. 
Me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de hacer que el programa continue solo, sin la necesidad de que intervenga el usuario.

Codigo completo:

```
printf("%s", mensaje);
fgets(cadena, 256, stdin);
longitud = strlen(cadena); 
if (longitud > numero) {
     printf("Longitud excesiva\n");
     while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> > El problema es que tras limpiar el buffer la consola se queda esperando hasta que se pulsa 'intro'.

¡Exacto! ¡Eso pasa porqué el búfer del teclado está limpio!

Primero que nada debemos saber como funciona la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). Y eso lo vamos a entender con este simple ejemplo:

```
char saludo[6];
fgets(saludo, 6, stdin);
```

Supongamos que el usuario ingresa un `Hola` por teclado, la función `fgets` enviará la cadena `Hola` hacia el búfer `saludo`, adicionalmente también incluirá el salto de línea en el arreglo, siempre y cuando la cantidad de caracteres leídos sea menor al tamaño máximo restado menos uno (`N - 1`). En este caso se leyeron `4` caracteres y es menor que `5` (por esa razón el `\n` se agrega al búfer).

El búfer `saludo` quedaría así:

```
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  | 5
H | o | l | a | \n | \0
```

**Nota:** El búfer del teclado esta limpio, por lo tanto no debemos hacer ninguna limpieza.

Ahora que pasaría si ingreso por teclado: `Holas`.

El búfer `saludo` quedaría de esta forma:

```
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  | 5
H | o | l | a | s  | \0
```

Sin embargo, en este caso la función `fgets` no incluirá el salto de línea (porqué la longitud coincide con el tamaño máximo restado menos uno) en el arreglo `saludo`, porqué ha leído 5 caracteres (`Holas`) y su longitud es igual a `5` (se resta menos 1 porqué los arreglos se empiezan a contar desde 0).

**Nota:** En este caso si se debe limpiar el búfer del teclado, debido a que el salto de línea quedó en el búfer.

Ahora, que pasaría si ingreso por teclado: `Holass`.

El arreglo `saludo` tendría lo mismo que antes:

```
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4  | 5
H | o | l | a | s  | \0
```

Sin embargo, el búfer del teclado se quedó con lo siguiente:

```
s\n
```

El último caracter `s` no se pudo enviar al búfer `saludo` porqué no había más espacio (porqué la función `fgets` ya leyó `N-1` caracteres) y como toda cadena, el caracter nulo siempre tiene un lugar reservado.

Por lo tanto, si se necesita limpiar el búfer en este caso.

**Entonces, ¿cómo sé cuando debo limpiar el búfer?**

Se necesita detectar si el último caracter del búfer `saludo` se quedó con un salto de línea o no.

Entendiendo una parte del funcionamiento de la función `fgets`, podemos proceder a analizar paso a paso tu código:

```
const int numero = 200;
printf("%s", mensaje);
fgets(cadena, 256, stdin);
longitud = strlen(cadena); 
if (longitud > numero)
{
    printf("Longitud excesiva\n");
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Supongamos que el usuario ingresa por teclado: `hhhh`. Serían 5 caracteres, debido a que, el salto de línea se incluyó en el búfer `cadena` (porqué la cantidad de caracteres que se han leídos son menores a `N-1` (en este caso `N` es `256`)). Por lo tanto, el búfer del teclado quedó limpio y por esa razón la función `fgetc` pausa el programa, debido a que, no encontró ningún caracter en el búfer del teclado.

**¿Cuando la función `fgetc` no pausará el programa?**

Cuando el búfer del teclado esté sucio.

**Solución:**

Solo debes limpiar el búfer del teclado cuando esté sucio.

```
if (longitud > numero)
{
    printf("Longitud excesiva\n");
    //Si el último caracter no es un salto de línea, podemos asumir que el búfer esta sucio.
    if(cadena[longitud-1] != '\n')
        //Limpiamos el búfer.
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Otra posible solución es usando la biblioteca [PScanf](https://github.com/MrDave1999/pscanf.h). Con esta biblioteca no necesitas preocuparte en limpiar el búfer del teclado ni tener que agregar el tamaño del arreglo.

Por ejemplo, tu código puede ser transformado a esto usando [PScanf](https://github.com/MrDave1999/pscanf.h):

```
const int numero = 200;
string cadena = {NULL};

strread(&cadena, "Ingrese una cadena:");
if (cadena.length > numero)
{
    printf("Longitud excesiva\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tengo como 20 años que no hago nada en C++, pero quizás te pueda ayudar, creo que el problema no se de buffer, ni de teclado, ni de consola, tendría que ver el código completo, pero cuando tienes cadenas, todas deberían tener un ascii 0 al final de la cadena, lo que quiere decir es que si metes 200 caracteres en una variable de 200, char "cadena[200]" no tienes espacio para el ascii 0, lo que conlleva a ver información aleatoria de la memoria, por otro lado el fgetc, no me gusta mucho, porque cuando los archivos son muy grandes, no importa la velocidad de disco, es muy lento en cargar... En archivos utilizo el ascii 219 como separador de campos y uso no recuerdo si fread con un puntero indeterminado, para que lea el tamaño completo del archivo, claro, procura que no sea en gigas y cosas así, si es de gigas, usas un puntero determinado como para 256 kb y lo haces con el while que tienes, pero no de carácter por carácter.  Tienes que usar "stdlib" y "stdio" u otros pero ya no recuerdo,  me encantaba usar malloc y otros funciones para crear listas y funcionaban tan rápido como el HANA u otros.  En VC, o PRO C, también lo usé, pero no recuerdo.  De todas forma espero haberte ayudado, y si puedo completar mejor la ayuda, no dudes en avisarme, esos temas me gustan mucho.