# Como convertir los procesos de ingreso y presentación de datos en una función void

Tags: c

Dado el siguiente código debo usar la función void para que en ella se realicen los procesos de presentación e ingreso de datos ya que estos procesos se repiten 3 veces dentro del mismo programa, pude completar el programa sin usar el void, pero al momento de intentar aplicar el void se presentan incoherencias en la presentación de los datos o errores en el ingreso de los datos.

El código funciona de la siguiente manera: Primero seleccionas la carrera a la que perteneces y posteriormente ingresas tus datos y luego son presentados, eso es todo.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

    #include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
//Creacion de la estructura de estudiantes
struct estructura_estudiantes
{
    char cedula[10],nombres[30],apellidos[30],semestre[2],materias[100];
    char carrera[];
};
main()
{
//Declaración de variables
//(sistema) es la variable que mantiene activo el while siempre que este sea igual a 1
//(i) es la cantidad de estudiantes
//(O_carrera) corresponde a la variable que selecciona la opcion del switch
int sistema=1,i,O_carrera;
//La estructura (estructura_estudiantes) adquiere el nombre de (estudiante) con (i) cantidad de estudiantes
//(*p_estudiantes) es el puntero
struct estructura_estudiantes estudiante[i],*p_estudiante;
//(num_estudiante) es el contador de los estudiantes
int num_estudiante;
//El While permite mantener abierto el menu de opciones en un bucle.
while(sistema==1)
{
    system("cls");
    printf("Benvenido al sistema de control de los estudiantes de la facultad de ciencias matemáticas y físicas de la UG.\n");
    printf("Elija la carrera de la que se llevara el control pulsando 1, 2 o 3:\n");
    printf("1. Software.\n");
    printf("2. Ingenieria Civil.\n");
    printf("3. Networking.\n");
    scanf("%d",&O_carrera);
    //Se inicia el menu de opciones
    switch(O_carrera)
    {
        case 1:
            //Inicio de ingreso de datos
            printf("De cuantos estudiantes requiere llevar el control?\n");
            scanf("%d",&i);
            while (getchar()!='\n');
            p_estudiante=estudiante;
            for(num_estudiante=0;num_estudiante<i;num_estudiante++)
            {
                strcpy(estudiante[num_estudiante].carrera,"Software");
                printf("\nIngrese datos del estudiante %d:\n",num_estudiante+1);
                printf("Cedula: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].cedula);
                printf("Nombres: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].nombres);
                printf("Apellidos: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].apellidos);
                printf("Semestre: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].semestre);
                printf("Materias: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].materias);
                while (getchar()!='\n');
                p_estudiante++;
                //Finaliza el ingreso de todos los datos
            }
            //Inicia la presentacion de los datos
            p_estudiante=estudiante;
            for(num_estudiante=0;num_estudiante<i;num_estudiante++)
            {
                printf("\nDatos del estudiante %d:\n",num_estudiante+1);
                printf("Cedula: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->cedula);
                printf("Nombres: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->nombres);
                printf("Apellidos: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->apellidos);
                printf("Carrera: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->carrera);
                printf("Semestre: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->semestre);
                printf("Materias: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->materias);
                p_estudiante++;
            }
            //Finaliza la presentación de datos
            break;
        case 2:
            //Inicio de ingreso de datos
            printf("De cuantos estudiantes requiere llevar el control?\n");
            scanf("%d",&i);
            while (getchar()!='\n');
            p_estudiante=estudiante;
            for(num_estudiante=0;num_estudiante<i;num_estudiante++)
            {
                strcpy(estudiante[num_estudiante].carrera,"Ingenieria civil");
                printf("\nIngrese datos del estudiante %d:\n",num_estudiante+1);
                printf("Cedula: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].cedula);
                printf("Nombres: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].nombres);
                printf("Apellidos: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].apellidos);
                printf("Semestre: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].semestre);
                printf("Materias: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].materias);
                p_estudiante++;
                //Finaliza el ingreso de todos los datos
            }
            //Inicia la presentacion de los datos
            p_estudiante=estudiante;
            for(num_estudiante=0;num_estudiante<i;num_estudiante++)
            {
                printf("\nDatos del estudiante %d:\n",num_estudiante+1);
                printf("Cedula: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->cedula);
                printf("Nombres: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->nombres);
                printf("Apellidos: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->apellidos);
                printf("Carrera: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->carrera);
                printf("Semestre: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->semestre);
                printf("Materias: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->materias);
                p_estudiante++;
            }
            //Finaliza la presentación de datos
            break;
        case 3:
            //Inicio de ingreso de datos
            printf("De cuantos estudiantes requiere llevar el control?\n");
            scanf("%d",&i);
            while (getchar()!='\n');
            p_estudiante=estudiante;
            for(num_estudiante=0;num_estudiante<i;num_estudiante++)
            {
                strcpy(estudiante[num_estudiante].carrera,"Networking");
                printf("\nIngrese datos del estudiante %d:\n",num_estudiante+1);
                printf("Cedula: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].cedula);
                printf("Nombres: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].nombres);
                printf("Apellidos: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].apellidos);
                printf("Semestre: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].semestre);
                printf("Materias: ");
                gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].materias);
                p_estudiante++;
                //Finaliza el ingreso de todos los datos
            }
            //Inicia la presentacion de los datos
            p_estudiante=estudiante;
            for(num_estudiante=0;num_estudiante<i;num_estudiante++)
            {
                printf("\nDatos del estudiante %d:\n",num_estudiante+1);
                printf("Cedula: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->cedula);
                printf("Nombres: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->nombres);
                printf("Apellidos: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->apellidos);
                printf("Carrera: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->carrera);
                printf("Semestre: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->semestre);
                printf("Materias: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->materias);
                p_estudiante++;
            }
            //Finaliza la presentación de datos
            break;
        default:
            printf("No existe esta opcion");
            break;
    } //Finaliza el menu de opciones
    printf("\nDesea salir del sistema o realizar otro control? (Pulse 1 o 0):\n");
    printf("1.Realizar otro control.\n");
    printf("0.Salir.\n");
    scanf("%d",&sistema);
} //Sale del bucle del menu de opciones
system("cls");
printf("Gracias por usar nuestro sistema :)");
getch();
} //Finaliza el programa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema radica aquí:

```c
int i;
struct estructura_estudiantes estudiante[i];
```

Estás definiendo un arreglo de estructuras sin saber cual es su tamaño máximo de elementos y esto se debe porque no sabemos que valor tomará la variable `i`.

Existen varias alternativas para solucionar este problema:

**1.** Establecer el tamaño del arreglo como una expresión constante (es decir, un número).

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```c
//El número 50 es la expresión constante.
struct estructura_estudiantes estudiante[50];
```

**La desventaja** de esta solución es que limitas al programa a que solo pueda registrar hasta 50 informaciones por estudiante.

**2.** Podrías hacer uso de un [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (Variable-length array). Con este tipo de solución, no limitas al programa a que solo pueda almacenar 50 estudiantes.

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```c
printf("De cuantos estudiantes requiere llevar el control?\n");
scanf("%d",&i);
struct estructura_estudiantes estudiante[i];
```

La **desventaja** de esta solución es que no todos los compiladores tienen soporte para los [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array). Un gran ejemplo es la herramienta `cl.exe` de Visual Studio. Si compilas el código de arriba con `cl.exe`, dará error de compilación porque el tamaño del arreglo debe ser una expresión constante (es decir, que se conozca en tiempo de compilación). Sin embargo, el uso de los `VLA` puede ser peligroso, debido a que, hay más probabilidades de que ocurra [desbordamiento de pila](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_pila) (la pila es limitada, aunque dependerá de los recursos de la máquina) y esto hace que el programa deje de funcionar al instante y lo peor es que ni siquiera podemos saber cual es el error porque en este tipo de solución no hay forma de conocer si hubo una falla de asignación o no.

Así que si te interesa tener un programa portable y sin errores, no recomendaría esta solución, sin embargo, para fines académicas, la podrías usar.

**3.** Esta solución es la forma correcta de hacerlo en lenguaje C y es usando [memoria dinámica](https://es.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_en_C/Manejo_din%C3%A1mico_de_memoria).

Para usar memoria dinámica necesitamos usar la función [malloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/).

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```c
//Debemos incluir la cabecera stdlib, debido a que, el prototipo de la función malloc se encuentra en dicho archivo.
#include <stdlib.h> 


struct estructura_estudiantes* estudiante;
printf("De cuantos estudiantes requiere llevar el control?\n");
scanf("%d",&i);

//Esto crea en memoria un arreglo de estructuras de X elementos. Dependerá del valor que tenga la variable i.
estudiante = malloc(i* sizeof(struct estructura_estudiantes));
if(estudiante == NULL)
{
    printf("Falla en la asignacion de memoria!");
    return 1;
}

//El resto de código...

//Liberamos la memoria reservada con malloc
free(estudiante);
```

**¿Por qué esta solución es la manera correcta de hacerlo?**

La respuesta es sencilla. Permite detectar si hay un fallo de asignación y se lo puedo mostrar al usuario. Algo que en la **solución 2** no se podía hacer. Además podríamos afirmar que el código de la **solución 3** compilaría en cualquier compilador de C que siga el estándar (en la **solución 2** no lo podríamos afirmar).

Es tu decisión elegir con cual solución te quedarás. En este caso, seleccionaré la tercera alternativa y con esto, responderé a tu pregunta:

> > Como convertir los procesos de ingreso y presentación de datos en una función void

Simplemente debemos crear una función en la cual tenga un parámetro, donde almacenará el tipo de carrera al que pertenezca el estudiante.

El código quedaría de esta manera:

```c
void ingrePresent(const char* tipoCarrera)
{
    struct estructura_estudiantes* estudiante;
    int i, num_estudiante;
    struct estructura_estudiantes* p_estudiante;
    printf("De cuantos estudiantes requiere llevar el control?\n");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    estudiante = malloc(i* sizeof(struct estructura_estudiantes));
    if(estudiante == NULL)
    {
        printf("Falla en la asignacion de memoria!");

        return;//Termina la ejecución de la función.
    }
    while (getchar()!='\n');
    for(num_estudiante=0;num_estudiante<i;num_estudiante++)
    {
        strcpy(estudiante[num_estudiante].carrera, tipoCarrera);
        printf("\nIngrese datos del estudiante %d:\n",num_estudiante+1);
        printf("Cedula: ");
        gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].cedula);
        printf("Nombres: ");
        gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].nombres);
        printf("Apellidos: ");
        gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].apellidos);
        printf("Semestre: ");
        gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].semestre);
        printf("Materias: ");
        gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].materias);
        while (getchar()!='\n');
    }
    p_estudiante=estudiante;
    for(num_estudiante=0;num_estudiante<i;num_estudiante++)
    {
        printf("\nDatos del estudiante %d:\n",num_estudiante+1);
        printf("Cedula: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->cedula);
        printf("Nombres: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->nombres);
        printf("Apellidos: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->apellidos);
        printf("Carrera: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->carrera);
        printf("Semestre: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->semestre);
        printf("Materias: | %s |\n",p_estudiante->materias);
        p_estudiante++;
    }

    //No olvides de liberar la memoria
    free(estudiante);
}
```

Y la forma de llamar a la función sería de esta forma:

```c
int main()
{
    int sistema=1, O_carrera;
    while(sistema==1)
    {
        system("cls");
        printf("Benvenido al sistema de control de los estudiantes de la facultad de ciencias matemáticas y físicas de la UG.\n");
        printf("Elija la carrera de la que se llevara el control pulsando 1, 2 o 3:\n");
        printf("1. Software.\n");
        printf("2. Ingenieria Civil.\n");
        printf("3. Networking.\n");
        scanf("%d",&O_carrera);
        switch(O_carrera)
        {
            case 1:
                ingrePresent("Software");
            break;
            case 2:
                ingrePresent("Ingenieria Civil");
                break;
            case 3:
                ingrePresent("Networking");
                break;
            default:
                printf("No existe esta opcion");
                break;
        }
        printf("\nDesea salir del sistema o realizar otro control? (Pulse 1 o 0):\n");
        printf("1.Realizar otro control.\n");
        printf("0.Salir.\n");
        scanf("%d",&sistema);
    } 
    system("cls");
    printf("Gracias por usar nuestro sistema :)");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Y de este modo, reutilizamos código y es mucha más eficiente para el programador, ya que evitas repetir el mismo código en X lugar.

**Observaciones:**

**1.** No deberías usar la cabecera `conio.h`, debido a que, no forma parte de la biblioteca estándar de C, por lo tanto, tendrás problemas de portabilidad (no se asegura que en un compilador te pueda funcionar, por lo tanto, posiblemente haya algún error de compilación). Para más información: [¿Por qué NO usar conio.h C?](https://www.taringa.net/+ciencia_educacion/por-que-no-usar-conio-h-c-c_ze6jo).

Así que no necesitas usar la función `getch`. Simplemente usa [getchar](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/).

**2.** No uses la función [gets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/) para pedir cadenas por teclado. Esta rutina es insegura, debido a que, no detecta el tamaño máximo de caracteres que puede almacenar un arreglo, por lo tanto, ocurrirá [desbordamiento de búfer](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desbordamiento_de_b%C3%BAfer).

**Ejemplo del error:**

```c
printf("Nombres: ");
gets(estudiante[num_estudiante].nombres);
```

El Tamaño máximo de caracteres que soporta el miembro `nombres` es de 30. Si el usuario llegara a escribir 40 caracteres, estarías pasando del límite del arreglo `nombres`. Por lo tanto, ocurrirá el desbordamiento y este tipo de error es difícil de depurar, porque posiblemente sobreescriba algún espacio de memoria propio del programa. ¡Así que mucho cuidado!

Una posible solución es usar la función [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/). Esta rutina por lo menos te deja especificar la cantidad máxima de caracteres que puede tener almacenado un arreglo.

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```c
printf("Nombres: ");
fgets(estudiante[num_estudiante].nombres, 30, stdin);
```

Por más que el usuario escriba más de 30 caracteres por teclado, la función `fgets` solo leerá hasta 30, los demás caracteres restantes se quedarán en el búfer. Por lo tanto se necesita saber en que momento se limpia el búfer o no. También debemos tomar en cuenta que esta función incluirá el salto de línea en el arreglo, siempre y cuando, `fgets` lea una cantidad de caracteres menores al tamaño máximo del arreglo. En este enlace explico sobre el funcionamiento de la función `fgets`: [Al limpiar buffer de entrada la consola espera hasta que se teclee algo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/318786/al-limpiar-buffer-de-entrada-la-consola-espera-hasta-que-se-teclee-algo/318807#318807).